# Cannot access local site through ports (Apache)

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, port

I've set ports 81 to 86 in Apache to access my local sites from Windows or my phone, they work fine but any other port, gives a 403 error.

httpd.conf file:

```
LISTEN 81
LISTEN 82
LISTEN 83
LISTEN 84
LISTEN 85
LISTEN 86
LISTEN 8080
```

Anything other than ports 81 to 86 will not work. I've allowed the ports through ESET Firewall and my httpd-vhosts.conf looks like this at the buttom:

```
     # site 7 in SSL:
 <VirtualHost *:8080>
     DocumentRoot "D:/some/address/here"
     ServerName site.test
     ServerAlias *.site.test
     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile "crt/site.test/server.crt"
     SSLCertificateKeyFile "crt/site.test/server.key"
     <Directory "D:/some/address/here">
       Require all granted
       AllowOverride All
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Setup your port 8080 exactly like your ports 81-86, and remove all SSL configuration.  This will allow you to make sure all ip tables, firewall, security is configured properly.  Then add your ssl.  This way you only debug one thing at a time.  Also put your LogLevel to trace8 and restart.   You will get a LOT of logs, to help you figure out the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line to my "httpd-vhosts.conf" file, under `DocumentRoot "D:/some/address/here"` fixed the issue:

```
<Directory "D:/some/address/here">
  Require all granted
  AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

The only strange thing for me is that how come ports 81 to 86 didn't need this code in httpd-vhosts.conf file...